# This phrase needs a comma or a colon?

Tags: punctuation, commas, colons

Phrase:

> The goal of this project is to translate to English and make more accessible the resources: resource1 and resource2, which are descriptions ...

The punctuation on this phrase is correct? Do I need to add/delete any commas or add a comma here?

> accessible, the resources:...

Sorry, this is a really important paper for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Colons are fine. They help you *list* the things. Here, you are *actually* listing the resources.

A comma would simply seperate them from each other making it a series. Also, if you put a comma, it doesn't complete the sentence: *more accessible...* what? You need a pronoun or noun there to complete it: *...make **it** more accessible...* but that's not the case I think.

I can help you more if you post the *whole* paragraph. The sentence is confusing as it is.

Comment: The phrase: " The goal of this project is to translate to english and make more accessible the resources: resource1 and resource2, which are descriptions of many algorithms and data structures especially popular in field of competitive programming. "